# Getting error in writing variable

Tags: php

I am writing this code in php

```
$a = 1 + 2 + 3 − 4 + 5;
echo $a;
```

getting error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'âˆ’' (T_STRING) in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\practice\test\index.php on line 2

what's the problem what's the right code

Comment: The problem is with this `−` that's not a true minus sign, but a similar character. Replace it with `-`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the operators and type them in again yourself. Looks like you copied them from somewhere and its not the correct operators php is expecting.

Eg. - and − are not the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to SO, where the simplest answers can make you a pointsmillionaire :)

Comment: [**this**](http://codepad.org/iC1MNkq7) shows the difference in URL encoded values between the two.

Comment: I guess you are the STAR of StackOverflow :)